# Using closures in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

What is the difference in the use of the below methods?

**First Method :**

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(e){
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(e); 
        }, 1000);
    })(i);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    createTimeoutFunction(i);
}
```

**Second Method :**

```
function createTimeoutFunction(e){ 
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(e); 
    }, 1000);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    createTimeoutFunction(i);
}
```

I am new to node js and in using closures. Though both methods return the same output but the second method runs with error. I am not understanding why do we need to use two loops as in the first method. Can't we just execute as like the second method?

Comment: the First Method is a little bit buggy because `createTimeoutFunction` doesn't exist

Comment: What kind of error does the second method give you?

Comment: @raina77ow If i try the above code in the terminal for the second method it prints `Array
Boolean
Date
Error
EvalError
Function
Infinity
JSON
Math
NaN
Number
Object
RangeError
ReferenceError
RegExp
String
SyntaxError
TypeError
URIError
decodeURI
decodeURIComponent
encodeURI
encodeURIComponent
eval
isFinite
isNaN
parseFloat
parseInt
undefined
` 10 times for `function createTimeoutFunction(e){`. Why is this so?

Comment: @user850234 I suppose it's because of REPL nature. How it behaves when you change the first line to `var createTimeoutFunction = function(e)...`?

Comment: @user850234 BTW, is there any error when you just run it (with `node somescript.js`)?

Comment: @raina77ow when i run with `node somescript.js` there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closure in javascript works the same regardless of the environment or interpreter that you're using.

A closure provides a specific variable scope in which that set of code executes.  Your closure will have access (obviously) to anything defined within itself, as well as any objects defined in any enclosing closure.

The problem with you code up there is that in the first example `createTimeoutFunction` isn't defined anywhere -- when you call it it will fail.  In that example:

```
(function(e){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(e); 
    }, 1000);
})(i);
```

The function being defined within this closure is an anonymous function.  It has no `name` property and can't be referenced.

The second version defines a global variable `createTimeoutFunction` which is then accessible in ANY closure on the page since it's part of the global object.  (Well I'm assuming that since you're not showing that this code is enclosed by anything else).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second `for` in your first method, because unless you want the loop to run twice, it is redundant as everything is already happening in the first. The second loop fails because `createTimeoutFunction` is never defined outside of the scope of the first loop, as opposed to the second method.

Other than that, they both will produce the same result, the only difference being in the second method `createTimeoutFunction` is reusable.

See also: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)